# Strategies for performing lots of world coordinate calculations in Blender

Tags: python, vertices, coordinates

I have a lot of calculations I need to do on meshes using global coordinates (distances between vertices, surface areas regions, etc.), and my script is getting slow.  I am wondering if there are any useful strategies to avoid having to constantly re-multiply vertex coordinates by matrix_world every time I need to loop over a set of vertices.  For example, it would be great if there were an "operate in world coordinates" mode, or a way to convert all local coordinates to their global coordinates.

```
# loop outline that is performed often
mat1 = ob1.matrix_world
mat2 = ob2.matrix_world
for v1_ind in verts1:
    v1 = mat1 * ob1.data.vertices[v1_ind].co
    for v2_ind in verts2:
        v2 = mat2 * ob2.data.vertices[v2_ind].co
        # computations
```

Further, is a way to use Blender's polygon.area to obtain the area of a face in global coordinates, or do I have to calculate it myself using the global coordinates of each vertex defining the face (slower)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply apply transformation, scale and rotation to the object before doing vertex calculations. This transforms all vertices to world coordinates (and pretty fast as well!).

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
```

You probably need to copy the object first if you want to keep the old transformations though.

Comment: Thanks Parkuhr.  In my case I only ever care about the global coordinates,  so this is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should cache the result of the inner loop.

```
verts2 = [mat2 * ob2.data.vertices[v2_ind].co for v2_ind in verts2]
```

and might do this for the outer loop as well

```
verts1 = [mat1 * ob1.data.vertices[v1_ind].co for v1_ind in verts1]
```

Generally you *might* gain performance by keeping python objects rather than doing an attribute / index lookup each time.

Tested with suzanne subdivided 3 times:

```
import bpy
import timeit
log = bpy.data.texts['log']
log.clear()

stmt_setup = """
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
vertices = obj.data.vertices
mat_world = obj.matrix_world
indices = range(len(vertices))"""

stmt_vertex_iter = """
verts_world = [mat_world * v.co for v in vertices]"""

stmt_index_lu = """
verts_world = [mat_world * obj.data.vertices[i].co for i in indices]"""

time_lc = timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt_vertex_iter, setup=stmt_setup, number=100)
time_il = timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt_index_lu,    setup=stmt_setup, number=100)

log.write("Vertex Iterator %.4f \n" % time_lc)
log.write("Index Look Up %.4f \n" % time_il)
```

yields

```
Vertex Iterator 2.5746 
Index Look Up 4.8094
```

Comment: [Discussion on Blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?377926-TEST-Bmesh-performance-tests/page2)

Comment: Thanks pink vertex, storing the vertices as a python list is undoubtedly the most general solution to this problem.  (And I'll vote for your answer as soon as I have enough reputation for the system to allow it...)

Answer (score 2):

**transform methods**

Given the accepted answer, this can be done via

```
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
me.transform(ob.matrix_world)
ob.matrix_world = Matrix() # set to identity since verts now global
```

Similarly with `bmesh` and particularly handy for calculating face areas etc.  The transformed bmesh need not be written back to the mesh, just as a way to keep track of geometry in global (or otherwise matrix transformed) coordinates.

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
bm.transform(ob.matrix_world) # bm vert coords now global

total_global_face_area = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)
```

**Numpy.**

Numpy can be used for quick matrix multiplication over vectors in a list.  See [Replace matrix @ vector list comprehensions with something more efficient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139511/replace-matrix-vector-list-comprehensions-with-something-more-efficient)

to apply the global transform to all vertices